# Disable jquery tooltip on focus

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tooltip, jquery-ui-tooltip

I want to disable the jqueryui tooltip on focus on input and select elements.
But only for the focused element. All other elements should show tooltip on hover.
On blur the tooltip of the element should be enabled.

Now I have:

```
var TheTooltip = $( document ).tooltip({
              items: ".tooltip"
              }
        }).on('focus', 'input, select', function() {
            TheTooltip.tooltip("close").tooltip("disable");
        }).on('blur', 'input, select', function() {
            TheTooltip.tooltip("open").tooltip("enable");
        });
```

But this disables all tooltips from the site.
If I change TheTooltip to $(this) I get an error message.

Comment: remove class `tooltip` from the elements on which you don't want the tooltip to appear

Answer (score 4):

This will make it so that the tooltip only displays on hover.

```
$(document).tooltip({
    items: ":hover"
});
```

Answer (score 2):

What you have certainly works but there's a much simpler way to do it with jQuery's default selectors ([`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and [`:focus`](http://api.jquery.com/focus-selector/)):

```
$(document).tooltip({
    items: ".tooltip:not(:focus)"
});
```

[Here's a jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6PUZz/)

---

If you want to use the tooltip's open/close functions, you [shouldn't delegate them](https://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#method-open). You had the right idea about `focus` and `blur` event handlers:

```
$(".tooltip").tooltip();
$(".tooltip").focus(function(evt) {
    // evt.currentTarget === this, unless you use $.proxy
    $(evt.currentTarget).tooltip("close");
});
```

[Here's an update](http://jsfiddle.net/6PUZz/2/)

This is perhaps more complex but a bit less fragile than manipulating the `input`'s classes; I'd still recommend going for it if non-delegated tooltips are an option

Comment: This looks really simple, and works quite fine, but don't close the open tooltip on focus.

Comment: if u use only not(:focus) the tooltip won't work for items that are hovered but also has the focus, i would suggest :hover, if u want to show tooltips only for hovered items

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working solution.
If there is a more simple way, you can tell me.

```
        $( document ).on('focus', 'input.tooltip, select.tooltip', function() {
            $(this).removeClass("tooltip").addClass("hadtooltip");
            $(this).tooltip().tooltip("close");
        }).on('blur', 'input.hadtooltip, select.hadtooltip', function() {
            $(this).addClass("tooltip").removeClass("hadtooltip");
        });
```